# Has_many on a ModelAdmin

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4, modeladmin

I have two DataObjects on Silverstripe 4.
First a Quiz whith a has_many-relationships with the questions for that Quiz.

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\DateField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\LiteralField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\CheckboxField;

class Quiz extends DataObject {

    private static $db = [
    "Name" => "Varchar(200)",
    "bis" => "Date()",
    "aktiv" => "Boolean",
    "Mail" => "Boolean",
    "MailText" => "Text"
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
    ];

    private static $has_many = [
    "Fragen" => Quiz_Fragen::class
    ];
```

The code for the questions.

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextareaField;

class Quiz_Fragen extends DataObject {

    private static $db = [
    "Frage" => "HTMLText",
    "Art" => "Enum(array('auswählen','MC','Text','Check'))",
    "OP1" => "Varchar(400)",
    "OP2" => "Varchar(400)",
    "OP3" => "Varchar(400)",
    "OP4" => "Varchar(400)",
    "Foul" => "Varchar(50)",
    "Team" => "Enum(array('A','B'))",
    "Punkte" => "Varchar(200)",
    "Down" => "Enum(array('1','2','3','4','Try','FK'))",
    "Pos" => "Varchar(25)",
    "Distanz" => "Varchar(2)",
    "Uhr" => "Enum(array('Snap','Ballfreigabe','Down ohne Zeit','keine','läuft'))",
    "Sonstiges" => "Varchar(50)",
    "Antwort" => "HTMLText",
    "SortOrder" => "Int",
    "Grund" => "HTMLText",
    "Pkt" =>"Enum(array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'))"
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
    "Quiz" => Quiz::class
    ];

    private static $has_many = [

    ];
```

In Silverstripe 3 I chose a entry of the dataobject quiz an had a link on the top to see the questions related to the chosen quiz. I miss this link in Silverstripe 4. I'm sure I'm just missing a little thing. But I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was the FieldList. 
On the dataobject Quiz I added the fields this way.

```
$fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name','Name des Quiz'),
            DateField::create('bis','Quiz läuft bis'),
            LiteralField::create("Text", "Vor der Aktivierung die Fragen eintragen. Sobald aktiviert wird bekommen die Benutzer eine E-Mail.<br /><br />"),
            CheckboxField::create('aktiv', 'Quiz aktivieren')
        );
```

When I use the old way of my SS 3 version. It works. So the problem is solved.